# How to use @yield into @include in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

How to use `@yield` into `@include` in laravel

```php
@include("layout.common.common-header",["title"=> @yield('title') ,"description"=>"description"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `View::getSection('title')` for get `@yield('title')`

```php
@include("layout.common.common-header",["title"=> View::getSection('title'),"description"=>"description"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try,

```
@include('layout.common.common-header',['title' => new Illuminate\Support\HtmlString($__env->yieldContent('title')) ,'description'=>'description'])
```